# PHP Active Record using NOW() in condition

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm trying to find all rows that have an `end_time` greater than the current time. In MySQL I believe I can use:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE end_time > DATE(NOW());
```

So, I'm trying to use:

```
$options = array();
$options['conditions'] = array('end_time > ?', array('DATE(NOW())'));
$results = Model::all($options);
```

But it doesn't appear to be working. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to fix this is to use:

```
$options['conditions'] = array('end_time > DATE(NOW())');
```

Wondering if this is the best solution.